# how can I re-draw ng-repeat when changes to an array are made?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an array of objects and each object can have slightly different data. I using ng-repeat on a directive that selects the correct directive to display. That "display" directive takes the object and displays the data in the correct format. This all works great.

Now I need to reorganize the order of the array. When I update the array, the "display" directives do not re-order, only the data changes. For example most of the data sets have a 'title' field, so those update, but the "display" does not.

How would I best refresh the ng-repeat so that it would properly re-order the "display" directives?

I can post code, but I feel this is more of a conceptual question.

HTML:

```
 <module-builder module="{{$index}}" ng-repeat="module in build.modules track by $index"></module-builder>
```

module-builder:

```
    (function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.email_editor')
        .directive('moduleBuilder', moduleBuilder);

    function moduleBuilder ($compile) {
        var directive = {
            link: link,
            restrict: 'EA'
        };
        return directive;

        function link(scope, element, attrs) {
            var module = scope.build.modules[attrs.module];
            var template = '';
            switch (module.Name){
                case 'moduleTypeOne':
                    template = "<module-type-one class='{{module.Class}}'></module-type-one>";
                    break;
                case 'moduleTypeTwo':
                    template = "<module-type-two class='{{module.Class}}'></module-type-two>";
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            element.html(template);
            $compile(element.contents())(scope);
        }
    }

})();
```

data sample:
[image]

**BTW html5Sotable is the interface for re-ordering**

Comment: Can you provide some sample code? The [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) says `When items are reordered, their respective templates are reordered in the DOM.` Perhaps you also need to use `track by` in the expression?

Comment: due to the two way binding nature of angular, this is actually an implementation question and not a conceptual question.  There are filters built in for managing order of objects which work perfectly, but the angular documentation mentions "You need to be aware that the JavaScript specification does not define the order of keys returned for an object." It's not clear if you are re-ordering the objects in the array, or simply re-ordering the keys of the objects.

Comment: Mentioned in the 2nd paragraph, the templates do not reorder, only the data does. I will prepare the code.

Comment: By using $compile to recompile the section you want re-ordered ?

Comment: also, you mention a `display` directive that takes an object,  seeing how this directive works may have something to do with why your items aren't re-ordering.

Comment: well the first thing is that `$index` isn't a representation of the item's position in an array, it's only an arbitrary value assigned by the `ng-repeat`.  so if you are using the `$index` value to try to find the right template to use from an array, you won't get the results you expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem in *track by $index*, in this case angular re-render element **only** if $index changed.
So, if you really have duplicated items in your array, you should track it by something else.

Comment: ok, so if i track by a server side, generated uid... curious, I will give this a shot.